# How to find the answer to the exercises in the book《tutorial》of Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I'm a beginner in Isabelle. I am reading the official document tutorial of Isabelle, and every time I see the exercises at the end of each chapter of the book, I want to know where to find the answers to these exercises.

Comment: It will be great if you can mention the link to the actual book.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to give a link to the book. The link to this book is http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2019/doc/tutorial.pdf
This link is the latest version of the book. The exercises in the previous version of the book should also be no different from this book.@Abhishek Garg

Comment: I think you are looking for this. https://isabelle.in.tum.de/exercises/solutions.html

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful for me.@Abhishek Garg